# Find changed or new rows in two lists of lists

Tags: python, list, search, iteration, python-2.4

I have two lists of lists which I call **old_rows** and **new_rows**.

Each row is a list of exactly 30 items. There may be a very large (and unknown) number of rows in each list. The two lists may contain different numbers of rows.

```
[ [row1_item1, row1_item2... row1_item30], 
  [row2_item1, row2_item2... row2_item30],
  ....
  [rowN_item1, rowN_item2... rowN_item30] ]
```

Where N is large and variable.

What I'd like to do is compare **old_rows** and **new_rows** and create a list of "significant differences" - I'm only interested in comparing about 10 items between rows. I already have a function which compares two rows for only those items.

So I tried this:

```
   changes = []
   for o, n in izip_longest(old_rows, new_rows):
      if not o:
         changes.append(output_row(None, n))
         continue
      if not n:
         continue
      if significant_differences(o, n):
         changes.append(output_row(o, n))
```

Annoyingly, this needs to work in Python 2.4, so **izip_longest** is out. Also the [code for izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) doesn't work as the unexplained **next** isn't 2.4-friendly.

Ideally looking for something pythonic and fast using a generator to cope with potentially very-large lists.

Comment: `tuple(map(next, iterators))` can be changed to `tuple(i.next() for i in iterators)` for Py <= 2.6 does that fix your problem? Alternatively `from operator import methodcaller` `tuple(map(methodcaller('next'), iterators))` which may be a little faster

Comment: Thanks your first line solved the problem. methodcaller was apparently introduced in 2.6 though.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll submit that as an answer then, you can accept it if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

can be changed to

```
tuple(i.next() for i in iterators)
```

for Py <= 2.6